# Slf4j using simple slf4j instead of logger4j

Tags: java, slf4j, lombok

I am writing a plugin for Minecraft, which uses Gradle to add additional code to a framework already made (Sponge).  When I try to use the @Slf4j annotation from Lombok, the only levels of logging I am able to use are info and above.  Based on a comment I saw on another post, this indicates it is using slf4j simple, which must already be built into the framework I am extending.  When I add logger4j as a dependency, slf4j continues to use simple slf4j instead of logger4j.  I would like to be able to use logger.debug and logger.trace in addition to the other methods.  Am I just not configuring something correctly?  How do I tell slf4j to use logger4j instead of simple slf4j?

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one implementation of slf4j. It will pick up one randomly. So if you want to use log4j instead of simple slf4, you may remove the simple-slf4j.jar from your class path.

modre detaile :http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings

And if you want to use  them at the same time, you can just use log4j directly without slf4j. For exmaple:

```
import org.apache.log4j.*;
public class LogTest {
  static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogTest.class.getName());
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     PropertyConfigurator.configure ("src/log4j.properties")；
     logger.debug("Debug ...");
     logger.info("Info ...");
     logger.warn("Warn ...");
     logger.error("Error ...");
 }
```

}